# asyncio.start_server not running inside pytest-asyncio test

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

When testing a server program using `asyncio.start_server()` it appears this method is not calling the first `client_connected_cb` method. When the program is run on its own outside of the test it works as expected. I suspect this has something to do with not working with the event loop properly.

To test, I have some non-async code to connect to the socket server which hangs indefinitely when listening to the socket.

Why isn't the event loop processing the server code inside of the unit test?

**Test:**

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_connect(server, connection):
    await server.start()
    connection.connect()
    connection.join_lobby('John')
    assert server.lobby.user_count() == 1
```

**Server:**

```
async def start(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = asyncio.start_server(self.new_client, self.HOST, self.PORT, loop = loop)
    self.server_coro = await loop.create_task(coro)
    print('Serving on {}'.format(self.server_coro.sockets[0].getsockname()))
```

**Connection code:**

```
def connect(self):
    self.s.connect((self.HOST, self.PORT))
    print('Just connected')

def join_lobby(self, name):
    self.s.send(b'Some data')
    print('Just tried to join lobby')
    msg = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print(msg)
```

The following output is displayed when the s.recv line is commented out. When s.recv is not commented the test hangs (because the server never sends data):

```
Serving on ('0.0.0.0', 8888)
Just connected
Just tried to join lobby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get to mix blocking and non-blocking code like that.  Your recv() call is blocking the whole thread and keeping your async server from running.  You'll have to make your client async as well.